# How can I remove the second Ubuntu at start up

Tags: uninstall

I had to uninstall and then reinstall Ubuntu. Now I show two Ubuntu choices in the menu when I start my computer. I searched google and have removed the extra kernel. That did not fix my problem. Does anyone know how to remove the second Ubuntu choice.

I can type what it looks like it only has three lines:

- Windows 7
- Ubuntu
- ubuntu

I dont think it was uninstalled correctly now that you mention it.

well i cannot seem to add comment to any of the posts so i dont know how to answer anyone but the answers provided didnt cover getting rid of one of the ubuntu.

Comment: Adding a screenshot of this second Ubuntu choice may help this question.  Since it's during boot and it may be hard to take a screenshot, I'll forgive you if it's a blurry camera-phone image of it, since it may be the easiest way.

Comment: You can edit your question body, and add more information, when replying to comments. For clarity, you can add new information under a heading `Updates` or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few possibilities.

1. Your old Ubuntu installation still exists, it wasn't removed.

   It's possible that when you re-installed, your new installation went to a different location - that is, a different partition, a different WUBI file, or a whole different drive.  All or part of the old installation may have remained.  How to fix this depends on your partition and drive layout and whether you installed using WUBI.
2. The second option you're seeing is simply the option that allows you to boot using an alternative kernel or some other options.  This is normal.

   If you don't want the boot menu to come up at all make sure you have `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` in your `/etc/default/grub` file and then make the changes effective using `sudo update-grub`.  Warning: this is not recommended if you are not a technical person and don't know how to, for example, rescue a system that can't boot.
3. There could have been a temporary problem updating Grub's configuration that simply needs a `sudo update-grub` to fix.